# bootstrap-select implementation not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am trying out an example of bootstrap-select, and it sort of works but has a bug at least in my implementation.

When I select an option,  it works.(EDITED: "Select all" is not actually working, as it does not put the selections in the box. I suspect it has something to do with the option divider I placed before all the options, because when I remove the divider, "Select All" works correctly) However, when I click outside of the element, and then click back on the element (perhaps the user wants to change a selection they made) it will not allow you to adjust any current selections you made. The only thing you can do to be able to make selections is to refresh the page and start over.

Here is a link to the live demo im working on:

[Example page im working on](https://aitenterprises.com/tracker/user_items.php)

Here is the CDN calls I am making for this project:

```html
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pjaaA8dDz/5BgdFUPX6M/9SUZv4d12SUPF0axWc+VRZkx5xU3daN+lYb49+Ax+Tl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!--  BOOTSTRAP SELECT -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>



    <link href="dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Here is the example code on that page:

```html
<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-actions-box="true">
<option data-divider="true"></option>
  <option>Mustard</option>
  <option>Ketchup</option>
  <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

EDIT 2:   Hopefully working Code Snippet is below--

```js
< script >
  $(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
  }) <
  /script>

  <
  script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(window).on('load', function() {

    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
      'selectedText': 'cat'
    });

    // $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('hide');  
  }); <
/script>
```

```css
.text-muted {
  font-size: small;
}

.text-bold {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: small;
}

.button {
  background-color: #008CBA;
  /* Light Blue */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 6px 10px;
}

.button2:hover {
  background-color: #008CBA;
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 17px 30px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  padding: 6px 10px;
}


/* Blue */

.button3 {
  background-color: #f44336;
}


/* Red */

.button4 {
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
  color: black;
}


/* Gray */

.button5 {
  background-color: #555555;
}


/* Black */

.button6 {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  background-color: #D35324;
  color: white;
}

.button6:hover {
  background-color: #037BA2;
  color: white;
}

td {
  text-align: left;
  valign="middle";
}

i {
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px;
}

.right {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.left {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.up {
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

.down {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #008CBA;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 120px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: #037BA2;
  padding: 6px 6px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #037BA2;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 3px;
  right: 0;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #037BA2;
}

input[id=Search],
select {
  padding: 8px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[value=Apply] {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  background-color: #D35324;
  color: white;
}

input[value=Reset] {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  background-color: #D35324;
  color: white;
}

input[value=Apply]:hover {
  background-color: #C44E22;
}

input[value=Reset]:hover {
  background-color: #C44E22;
}

table.table1,
th.th1,
td.td1 {
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: #008CBA;
}

.tooltip {
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 220px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent black transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}

.glyphicon.glyphicon-info-sign {
  font-size: 25px;
  top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<head>


  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pjaaA8dDz/5BgdFUPX6M/9SUZv4d12SUPF0axWc+VRZkx5xU3daN+lYb49+Ax+Tl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



  <!-- JQUERY -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!--  BOOTSTRAP SELECT -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />




  <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
  <link href="assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
  <script src="assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

  <h1> TEST FILE </h1><br><br>

  <select class="selectpicker" multiple data-actions-box="true">
    <option data-divider="true"></option>
    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Relish</option>
  </select>
  <br><br><br><br>
  <h1>END</h1>
  <p>NO MORE PAST HERE
    <p><br><br>
</body>
```

EDIT 3:

I have now verified that eveerything works correctly if I remove the following code:

```
<option data-divider="true"></option>
```

from the code I was using:

```
<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-actions-box="true">
<option data-divider="true"></option>
<option>Mustard</option>
<option>Ketchup</option>
<option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

So, the questions would be:
1.  What causes the Select All to not function when including the data-divider-true

2. What can I do to correct this so I can use the divider?

CURRENTLY WORKING SNIPPET - without using data-divider-true

```js
< script >
  $(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
  }) <
  /script>

  <
  script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(window).on('load', function() {

    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
      'selectedText': 'cat'
    });

    // $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('hide');  
  }); <
/script>
```

```css
.text-muted {
  font-size: small;
}

.text-bold {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: small;
}

.button {
  background-color: #008CBA;
  /* Light Blue */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 6px 10px;
}

.button2:hover {
  background-color: #008CBA;
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 17px 30px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  padding: 6px 10px;
}


/* Blue */

.button3 {
  background-color: #f44336;
}


/* Red */

.button4 {
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
  color: black;
}


/* Gray */

.button5 {
  background-color: #555555;
}


/* Black */

.button6 {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  background-color: #D35324;
  color: white;
}

.button6:hover {
  background-color: #037BA2;
  color: white;
}

td {
  text-align: left;
  valign="middle";
}

i {
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px;
}

.right {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.left {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.up {
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

.down {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #008CBA;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 120px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: #037BA2;
  padding: 6px 6px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #037BA2;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 3px;
  right: 0;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #037BA2;
}

input[id=Search],
select {
  padding: 8px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[value=Apply] {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  background-color: #D35324;
  color: white;
}

input[value=Reset] {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 8px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  background-color: #D35324;
  color: white;
}

input[value=Apply]:hover {
  background-color: #C44E22;
}

input[value=Reset]:hover {
  background-color: #C44E22;
}

table.table1,
th.th1,
td.td1 {
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: #008CBA;
}

.tooltip {
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 220px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent black transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}

.glyphicon.glyphicon-info-sign {
  font-size: 25px;
  top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<head>


  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pjaaA8dDz/5BgdFUPX6M/9SUZv4d12SUPF0axWc+VRZkx5xU3daN+lYb49+Ax+Tl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



  <!-- JQUERY -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!--  BOOTSTRAP SELECT -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />




  <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
  <link href="assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
  <script src="assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>
  <h3>START OF TEST</h3>
  <br><br>
  <p><div>
  <select class="selectpicker" multiple data-actions-box="true">

    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Relish</option>
  </select>
</div></p>

  <p><br><br><br></p>
  <h3>END OF TEST</h3>
  <p><br><br></p>



</body>
```

Comment: What browser are you using. I'm using chrome 69 and can't reproduce the problem you're describing. Aslo if you didn't modify or added any CSS or JS affecting the select you might need to create an issue in their github repo.

Comment: THanks for the reply, im on verion 68. Im going to upgrade to 69 and see if that helps. Will reply here with result.

Comment: Upgraded to 69 on chrome, rebooted, the problem still exists for me.  Tried in Safari, and I experience the same issue.

Comment: If that is the case you might want to create a working code snippet. The first 1 doesn't do anything any way. The second works so there is no way too see what is going wrong except for the provided link

Comment: Wish I could figure out how to do the code snippet correctly because every time I try, I can't seem to figure out how I am supposed to separate out my code. blah, I'm new to stack exchange, so my apologies.

Comment: Okay, I may have finally made some progress -- on two fronts.  I was able to get (i think) the code snippet part of this figured out. In using that i discovered that I was loading bootstrap-select and bootstrap in the wrong order. After correcting this, It appears to working correctly now Except for "Select All". That still does not work correctly.